# I need to replace index.php on server

Tags: wordpress, server, backup

I need to replace the `index.ph`. file on godaddy server so demo site is not shown anymore but instead my backup with avada child theme

this is my code now:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

what must I change ?

Any help is deeply appreciated